# admob error in game source app

Tags: android, eclipse

i have a problem by a game source, by MY_AD_UNIT_ID it's ok, i know my id code, but, by AD_INTERSTITIAL_UNIT_ID i don`t know where to find,

because by my admob code is the same like `ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx`

but where can find this one ? `"df2cce209f194168";` thx for help !

```
private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-1141613635835332/7968365003";

private static final String AD_INTERSTITIAL_UNIT_ID = "df2cce209f194168";
```

Comment: Create a new add unit on admob and pick interstitial and you will get the id.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for Banner Ad ID and Interstitial Ad ID.
Go to you admob account add new app and create Banner Ad Id and Interstitial Ad Id.

```
private static final String AD_UNIT_ID="Banner AD ID"
private static final String AD_INTERSTITIAL_UNIT_ID = "Interstitial AD ID";
```

Comment: i have it but in my admob account i have banner id and interstitial ad id look bouth the same like this : ca-app-pub-1141613635835332/7968365003 and i don`t find this small id: AD_INTERSTITIAL_UNIT_ID = "df2cce209f194168";

Comment: The value "df2cce209f194168" is for just demo please ignore it and paste your interstitial id and run the game/app.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static final String AD_INTERSTITIAL_UNIT_ID = "df2cce209f194168";
```

Here "df2cce209f194168" is dummy id, please replace it with your Interstitial Unit Id.